# What is native assets, Also Not able to send my ADA from Exodus Wallet

Tags: wallet

My name is Adam gil and I am crypto follower. I have been using Cardano from past few months. Recently I tried to send my ADA from Exodus wallet. I have 4600 ADA in my Exodus wallet.

The Issue - When I try to send my ADA, it is allowing me to send 0.776781 ADA and than it displays message saying “Transaction amount is too small to send”.

Next it shows a second message like - “**Needed for holding ADA native tokens:1.666665ADA**”

Tried multiple times and also by refreshing the system but it doesn't help.

Please help me to understand - what this Native Token is and where I get them?

If you need wallet address I can share in next message.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a minimum amount that can be held at a UTxO, see https://docs.cardano.org/native-tokens/minimum-ada-value-requirement.
I guess you have at least one cardano-native token in your wallet, perhaps you traded for one? If Exodus does not show this you can search your wallet address in an explorer such as https://cardanoscan.io/ to see your token balance.

Basically, you have to send more as to satisfy the network `minUtxo` constraint.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!